# How can I get the proper value of my checkbox instead of Null?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Currently I'm building a product page that has multiple filters in it. I want to get the value of my checkbox when it is checked by the user so I can display my code when checked. Have added a console.log to check it but only returns the error that it cannot read property of Null. What am I doing wrong?

My HTML

```
<h4>Some title</h4>
        <label class="container-filter">15 - 30 min.
                <input type="checkbox" value="15">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
        <label class="container-filter">30 - 60 min.
                <input type="checkbox" value="30">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
```

My Javascript

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var checkedValue =  document.querySelector('.boardgame:checked').value;
        console.log(checkedValue)
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily doable via using the `this` reference itself like so :-

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const checkedValues = {};
input.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('change', function() {
    checkedValues[this.value] = this.checked;
    console.log(checkedValues)
 });
});
```

```html
<h4>Some title</h4>
        <label class="container-filter">15 - 30 min.
                <input type="checkbox" value="15">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
        <label class="container-filter">30 - 60 min.
                <input type="checkbox" value="30">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
```

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase that, what I want to do is that when someone has checked off the checkbox it also needs to return the 15 or the 30 so I can use it for filtering.

Comment: @PHV I have updated the snippet to use a global object as a map to store all values with their true/false values. You can use that global object as required.